# navigator error in flutter navigator error The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<void> gotologin() async {
    await Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).push(  // <- The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Login(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and add, if possible, the entire class that has `gotologin` as a method?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your are having another variable of type JsObject that is named Context , try to rename that variable and try again or you can past the full page code and I will be happy to help you with it !